# Page crawler index is just searching the exact word in kentico

Tags: search, indexing, kentico

I created a page crawler index and I'm testing all search modes, with all page types in the index content. By the way, the index is just searching for the exact word. example if I'm looking for the word "test" I must to write "test" to find it but if I search for "tes" is not finding anything.
How can I update this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look more into Analyzer types and what suits you best. If you set it to 'Subset', then it will show you results for 'tes' but also for 'est'. In this [link](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-locally-stored-search-indexes/creating-local-search-indexes#Creatinglocalsearchindexes-Reference-Searchindexproperties), you can find more about them.